# How to remove sub path folder of pvc when call delete pods, ... with client-go k8s

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, client-go, amazon-efs

I using k8s/client-go library to control and develop my application (https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go).

I have an issue when use sub-path of persistent volume claim.
Example,  I'm having two pod and mount data of each container to 2 subpath `ORG1/DIR1` and `ORG2/DIR2` on persistent volume claim (`efs file`), detail in blow:

```yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-lamp-site
spec:
    containers:
    - name: mysql
      image: mysql
      env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: "rootpasswd"
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        name: site-data
        subPath: ORG1/DIR1
    - name: php
      image: php:7.0-apache
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/www/html
        name: site-data
        subPath: ORG1/DIR2
    volumes:
    - name: site-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: hpc-vinhha-test
```

And when I call to delete this pod, currently k8s only delete pod, and core lib not delete data of pod on `persistent volume claim`. So, data of PVC will become garbage and become bigger and bigger.

I want to delele all data in sub path `ORG1/DIR1` and `ORG1/DIR2` when pods deleted.

This is file yaml of pvc:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"efs-claim","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteMany"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"5Gi"}},"storageClassName":"efs-sc"}}
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-07-10T04:02:51Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: efs-claim
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "887409"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/efs-claim
  uid: ab66c2f7-744c-4d6f-a508-2bc90f0b1897
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: efs-pv-shared
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  phase: Bound
```

So, can you help me with this problem. Because I'm a newbie in k8s and aws-efs. So, I don't have much experience about it :(

Thank so much.

Comment: that's exactly how it should be. you dont want you persistent data to be deleted when a pod dies, otherwise it would be ephemeral data. 

if you expect those volumes/subPaths to be empty when mounting and want them to be deleted again when the pod dies, you might find emptyDir to be the right solution for your usecase instead of persistentvolumeclaims

Comment: @meaningqo because I want sharing data between from head node pod to some other node pods (ex: compute node, ...). Because I can run build my app and compile to binary with name `exec.bin`, put it on sub folder `ORG1/DIR2`, and all compute node can get file `exec.bin` from share folder `ORG1/DIR2` and execute.
This is my idea. :(

Comment: What reclaim policy did you use for your pvc? Can you share pvc manifest?

Comment: Oh yes, @MariuszK. I had attached file pvc yaml in description of question.